# Spring mvc resource issue

Tags: css, spring, model-view-controller, resources

I have a problem with mvc:resource,please take a look

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/app/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/css/"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/app/css/main.css" />">
```

And how can you see css styles not going to be find.
Here is project structure

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you are getting the '/app/' mapping from, you don't have a folder called 'app'?

Try with this instead:

```
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/css/" mapping="/css/**"></mvc:resources>
```

Comment: Yeah that was a problem, i got it earlier but thanks;)

Answer (score 0):

i do not find app folder, and remove app with WEB-INF it will work. code should be like as

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
<servletclass>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/WEB-INF/.**" location="/WEB-INF/css/"/>
```